# Use of website cookies based on the account logged in

Tags: php, search, cookies, save, user-input

Brainstorming for a feature right now, looking for advice and tips.

If this is possible to do, I would like to have a search bar save what the user has written and save the search (if there are results found) as a cookie. There will be up to three searches saved where the newest one that is accepted replaces the oldest one. My concern is that am I able to save these search cookies uniquely on every user account?

**My plan is the following:**

1. User searches

   - check if the search yields results.
   - save as cookie if a search is successful
2. Display on website

   - the purpose of the cookie is to show a product in our site homepage based on the searches
3. Save on individual accounts

   - the cookies used here should not transfer outside the account used at that time, if a new user logs 
     in, there will be no cookies.
   - if a user that searches logs back, the previous cookies will still be present and display products 
     accordingly.

My thoughts are this will be similar to my remember me login cookies that saves them with:

```
setcookie ("login_email",$_POST["email"],time()+ 3600);
setcookie ("login_password",$_POST["password"],time()+ 3600);
```

The website where is is going to be made is using PHP.

I would like some advice on what logic should I use on the code, thank you for reading and looking forward to any responses.

Comment: Why do you want to store the search results in a cookie and not use $_SESSION?